# ologit going for too many steps?

Tags: stata

I ran ologit for ordered logit but this is not ending, and I am getting the following message.

```
Iteration 1288: log pseudolikelihood = -341.13477  (not concave)
Iteration 1289: log pseudolikelihood = -341.13477  (not concave)
Iteration 1290: log pseudolikelihood = -341.13477  (not concave)
Iteration 1291: log pseudolikelihood = -341.13477  (not concave)
```

I am not sure if this is going to right direction or if I need to terminate this process.

Comment: On this (little) information, you should abandon the fitting; retreat to a simpler model whose fitting does converge; and then try complicating the model to see which predictors, or which model specification is problematic. Pay particular attention to predictors with very skewed or unequal distributions. But this isn't really a programming question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look up the `gologit2` package produced and documented by the excellent Richard Williams: [gologit2 page](http://www3.nd.edu/~rwilliam/gologit2/)

However, make sure you read the documentation and sufficiently understand the methods.  After that, read the linked materials in "troubleshooting FAQ" to help you figure out the actual model to use.

**Added after comments:**

The reasoning behind my advice to check out the documentation for `gologit2` is in the comments, but I'll reiterate here for the sake of completeness: logit and ologit models are fitted using maximum likelihood.  Sometimes these models don't "converge", i.e. can't find a maximal or minimal solution, because the probability function is complex.  In these cases, Stata will inform you that it finds the probability space to be non-concave.  You can try invoking the "difficult" option in your regression command.  If that fails, in the case of logit/ologit, sometimes relaxing the assumption of proportional odds/parallel lines can help the model converge.  This is what the `gologit2` command does.  But you also gave very little context for your model and data so make sure you read the documentation for `gologit2` to make sure you are using appropriate models.

Comment: `gologit2` is an excellent command, but why do you think it would help here? Is the implication that a slightly different model might fit better?

Comment: @NickCox, there was very little in the question to go on, but I've previously found that a logit model couldn't converge because of non-concavity in the probability space and that relaxing the assumption of proportional odds/parallel lines can help the model converge.  I hope that user42459 won't use gologit2 blindly but will take advantage of its excellent documentation to explore some alternative modeling approaches.  Is there a concern I should have considered?

Comment: Not that I know of; that sounds like excellent advice in your comments, but it would be better said explicitly in your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much @NickCox, I will keep it in mind in the future.  I kept my answer spare because it was a shot in the dark, given the lack of context in the original question.  But you are right that I should have explained my reasoning.